# Compare 2 strings in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The x.name and imgname have the same type (string) and the same value "comcardpro_capsule_model_2". But why the findIndex() function return -1?
Please explain it to me.

```
findPicture(imgname): number {
   return this.info.comcardList.findIndex(x => {
      x.name === imgname;          // result in console:
      console.log(imgname)         // comcardpro_capsule_model_2
      console.log(typeof imgname)  // string
      console.log(typeof x.name)   // string
      console.log(x.name);         // comcardpro_capsule_model_2
   })
  }
```

Expect result will be index of the element in array not -1.

Comment: you need add a return statement

Comment: Because you're NOT `returning` the result of the comparison. That's all that's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `findIndex` callback always returns undefined, you should instead `return x.name === imgname;`

The `findIndex` function essentially does something like

```
if (findIndexCallback(element)) return index;
```

for each element of the array. So if your function returns nothing (`undefined`), the fallback value of `-1` meaning "not found" is returned.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex for full documentation.

Comment: It works, thank you. But can you explain why we can not remove the 'return' in `return x.name === imgname;`

Comment: Single-statement/non-bracketed arrow functions don't need a return statement because it is implicit. `() => 5` is a function that returns 5. `() => { 5; }` is a function that returns undefined. If your function were just `x => x.name === imgname` it would also work.

Comment: `const fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cantaloupe", "blueberries", "grapefruit"];

const index = fruits.findIndex(fruit => fruit === "blueberries");

console.log(index); // 3
console.log(fruits[index]); // blueberries`

Answer (score 1):

you need add a return statement on your findIndex

```js
findPicture(imgname): number {
  return this.info.comcardList.findIndex(x => {
     return x.name === imgname;          // result in console:
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result from your findIndex function.

```
findPicture(imgname): number {
    return this.info.comcardList.findIndex(x => {
    return x.name === imgname;
    });
 }
```